# Happy parser rule order

Tags: haskell, happy

I ran into a case using Happy (a Haskell parsing package) where the order of seemingly independent rules affects its behavior in a strange way.

```
{
module Parser where
}
%name constFoo
%name constBar
%tokentype { Token }
%error { parseError }
%token
    foo          { Foo }
    bar          { Bar }
%%
constFoo : foo { Foo }
constBar : bar { Bar }
{
parseError :: [Token] -> a
parseError _ = error "Parse error"
data Token = Bar | Foo deriving Show
}
```

As I understand how Happy works, both of the parses `constFoo [Foo]` and `constBar [Bar]` should succeed.  However, with the above code, `constFoo [Foo]` succeeds but `constBar [Bar]` fails.  If I swap the order of the rules for `constFoo` and `constBar`, the latter succeeds and the former fails.

Is there some aspect to Happy's semantics that I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited - Happy's syntax allows you to specify the start production with the name directive:

```
%name parser constFoo
```

This creates a function called **parser** and it uses **constFoo** as the start production.

If you want parsers for both constFoo and constBar, this seems to be the syntax:

```
%name parser1 constFoo
%name parser2 constBar
```

I think in your original, both named parser functions (constFoo and constBar) defaulted to the first production in the grammar (constFoo).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that's the problem; if I remove `%name constFoo` then constBar exhibits the same strange order-dependent behavior.

Comment: Hi Judah - I've re-worked my answer as I miss read the Happy manual.